# Unable to access “Local Disk”

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

Hey i have dual boot windows and Ubuntu. When i installed ubuntu all Local Disks worked well but when some time past i can not access to local disk D. I have very important files there. I cant access to windows too it is broken.
When i try to mount local disk D it shows me the error:

> Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sda3: Command-line `mount
>   "/mnt/94EE82ACEE8285E8"' exited with non-zero exit status 13:
>   ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error Failed to
>   calculate free MFT records: Input/output error NTFS is either
>   inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
>   SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
>   then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
>   important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate it
>   and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
>   /dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
>   for more details.

Can i mount local disk somehow from Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In Windows:

We need to test/repair any Windows/NTFS partitions using `chkdsk`, and we need to disable `fast start` and `hibernation`.

- open an administrative command prompt window and type `chkdsk /f c:` and approve to run this at the next reboot time
- type `chkdsk /f d:` changing the "d" to any other drive letters that exist on your system
- disable `fast start` in the Power control panel

  open the `Power` control panel

  select `Change what power buttons do`

  select `Change options that are unavailable`

  uncheck `fast start`
- in the open administrative command prompt window, type `powercfg /h off`
- reboot Windows and let chkdsk test/repair the C: drive
- reboot Ubuntu and see if your drive is available now

Comment: Is there any way to do this from linux because i do not have access to windows, it is broken. @heynnema

Comment: Please describe what's going on with Windows, and what steps you have taken to fix it? Do you have a Windows installation/repair CD/DVD?

Comment: A few months ago i had a problem winload.exe expired...i fixed it only by changing the year to 2015 but when windows loading lockscreen suddenly it shows blue screen and it says: Stop Code:  PROCESS1 INITIALIZATION FAILED @heynnema

Comment: You didn't answer the question... Do you have a Windows installation/repair CD/DVD?

Comment: I have windows 10 installation DVD @heynnema

Comment: Set the date/time correctly in Ubuntu. Then boot to the Windows DVD and use it to try and repair your Windows. Google "using Windows DVD to repair Windows" online if you don't know how to use it in that capacity.

Comment: ok i will try to do this @heynnema

Comment: It worked now i can access local disk thank you @heynnema