# Unable to access “Relax”

Tags: mount

Someone can help me with this error:
When i try to access to drive i get this:

Unable to access “Relax”.

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb3: Command-line `mount "/mnt/8D73B70E3162A201"' exited with non-zero exit status 13: ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to calculate free MFT records: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access “Local Disk”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853612/unable-to-access-local-disk)

Comment: Grandfather question

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with NTFS format on drives.

The solution is:
FAT for windows compatibility, i don't have this issue of filesystem errors with FAT.

So backup you drive(if you can) and format you drive to FAT .