# How do I resolve "Unable to access location" error?

Tags: mount, hard-drive, crash, 23.04

While transferring files from an external hard drive my computer froze. After restarting I get an error whenever I try to open a hard drive.

[image: Image of error when opening external hard drive]

I also looked at syslogs, and at around the time my computer froze it says,

```
Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault
```

It then talks about running chkdsk.

What is this error about? How do I fix it? Will I lose my data, and how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to access “Local Disk”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/853612/unable-to-access-local-disk)